# grpc custom load balancer not detecting new server addition in cluster

Tags: go, grpc, load-balancing

I am building a distributed workflow orchestrator, grpc is used to communicate with the server cluster by workers.If a new server is added to the server grpc client is not able to detect this change. However i have done a workaround by adding a max connection age to the server options

```
grpc.KeepaliveParams(keepalive.ServerParameters{
        MaxConnectionAge: time.Minute * 1,
    })
```

We have two implementation of workers, one in golang and other in java this workaround works perfectly in golang client. Every minute the client makes new connection and is able to detect new servers in cluster. But this is not working with java client.

```
public CustomNameResolverFactory(String host, int port) {
    ManagedChannel managedChannel = NettyChannelBuilder
            .forAddress(host, port)
            .withOption( ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000 )
            .usePlaintext().build();
    GetServersRequest request  = GetServersRequest.newBuilder().build();
    GetServersResponse servers = TaskServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(managedChannel).getServers(request);
    List<Server> serversList = servers.getServersList();
    System.out.println(servers);
    LOGGER.info("found servers {}", servers);
    for (Server server : serversList) {
        String rpcAddr = server.getRpcAddr();
        String[] split = rpcAddr.split(":");
        String hostName = split[0];
        int portN = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        addresses.add(new EquivalentAddressGroup(new InetSocketAddress(hostName, portN)));
    }
}
```

Java client code- https://github.com/Mohitkumar/orchy-worker-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/orchy/client/CustomNameResolverFactory.java

Golang client code- https://github.com/Mohitkumar/orchy/blob/main/worker/lb/resolver.go

Comment: Hi Manoj, is this resolved ? I am also facing the similar issue